# JavaFX and jfxwebkit.dll

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-desktop

In my app, I used JavaFX to create a browser type page to display my Help.  Most of the application is written in Java using JRE 11.0.10.  I initially was using JavaFX 11.0.2 which worked fine.  My customer wanted us to move to JavaFX 11.0.10 which I did via Gluon's subscription service.  With JavaFX 11.0.10, the Help system crashes the whole application.  I have narrowed it down to the jfxwebkit.dll.  It works with version 11.0.2, but not with 11.0.10.

I use NetBeans 12.3 and use its JLink to create a customer JRE; though, for some reason, it still puts in "some" JavaFX 11.0.2 files instead of the 11.0.10 files even though I have eliminated the older version of JavaFX.  When I manually replace the said files with the JavaFX 11.0.10 files, the only one that causes the crash is jfxwebkit.dll.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I cannot debug it because it works in the IDE (not sure what jfxwebkit it is using).  Below is from the "hs_err_pid" file:

```
Current thread (0x0000024c5830b000):  JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=9000, stack(0x000000f7fcd00000,0x000000f7fce00000)]

Stack: [0x000000f7fcd00000,0x000000f7fce00000],  sp=0x000000f7fcdfc610,  free space=1009k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x3a8eb9]
C  [jfxwebkit.dll+0x8b1b0]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkCreatePage(Z)J+0 javafx.web
j  com.sun.webkit.WebPage.<init>(Lcom/sun/webkit/WebPageClient;Lcom/sun/webkit/UIClient;Lcom/sun/webkit/PolicyClient;Lcom/sun/webkit/InspectorClient;Lcom/sun/webkit/ThemeClient;Z)V+178 javafx.web
j  javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+287 javafx.web
j  javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>()V+3 javafx.web
j  javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>()V+60 javafx.web
j  com.austinnc.utilsjfx.CBrowser.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V+9 com.anc.UtilsJFX
j  com.austinnc.utilsjfx.CHelpDisplayJFX.displayHelp(Ljava/lang/String;)V+12 com.anc.UtilsJFX
j  com.austinnc.optfilegen.COptionFileGenFrame$CHelpEH$1.run()V+90 com.anc.OptionFileGenerator
j  com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Void;+1 javafx.graphics
j  com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$58.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+4 javafx.graphics
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1183  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.10 (0 bytes) @ 0x0000024c487cb9a6 [0x0000024c487cb940+0x0000000000000066]
j  com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)V+7 javafx.graphics
j  com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$57.run()V+8 javafx.graphics
j  com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run()V+4 javafx.graphics
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+0 javafx.graphics
j  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(ILjava/lang/Runnable;)V+8 javafx.graphics
j  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$46.run()V+12 javafx.graphics
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11 java.base@11.0.10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace at least? A SSCCE would be better of course.

Comment: Solved - it did not like a particular Look and Feel buried in some older code.

Comment: Please see this similar issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8246796. This could help.

Comment: The answer could have been usefull to others.